# Unable to convert the ORTH to String in spaCY

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

I got the frequency of the words but not word format. Can you please suggest how can I associate the ID with the word?

```
from spacy.attrs import ORTH

doc = nlp("apple is the man good orange apple orange banana")

print(Text.count_by(ORTH))
```

{8566208034543834098: 2, 3411606890003347522: 1, 7425985699627899538: 1, 3104811030673030468: 1, 5711639017775284443: 1, 2208928596161743350: 2, 2525716904149915114: 1}

Like how to associate "8566208034543834098" to apple?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Counter` instead of `count_by` to get a count of tokens/words:

```
import spacy
from collections import Counter

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

doc = nlp("apple is the man good orange apple orange banana")
word_freq = Counter([tok.text.lower() for tok in doc])
print(word_freq)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'apple': 2, 'orange': 2, 'is': 1, 'the': 1, 'man': 1, 'good': 1, 'banana': 1})
```

To convert `orth` to string:

```
print(doc.vocab[8566208034543834098].text)
```

Output

```
apple
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use count_by as below:

```
from spacy.attrs import ORTH

doc = nlp("apple is the man good orange apple orange banana")
counts = doc.count_by(ORTH)
{nlp.vocab.strings[word_id]:count for word_id, count in counts.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'apple': 2, 'is': 1, 'the': 1, 'man': 1, 'good': 1, 'orange': 2, 'banana': 1}
```